# Alternatives to Rails' client_side_validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

[client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) was a widely used gem that automatically created realtime validations for your Rails' frontend based on your models' validations. Alas, it seems to be unmaintained now. Are there any similar, maintained alternatives out there?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Judge Rails Gem: https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge and there are plugins to use with FormBuilder SimpleForm https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge-simple_form

Comment: [client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) has a new owner. At now, the project is compatible with Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 3):

parsley.js is really nice -http://parsleyjs.org/ and it's been made into a gem for rails here - https://github.com/mekishizufu/parsley-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [jQuery.validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation). Although I think parsley looks a little better.

Comment: BTW -- there is a rails gem for jQuery validation: https://github.com/danryan/jquery-validation-rails